# Command not found -bash error

Tags: bash, mac, terminal

I am noticing that after I did something with terminal attempting to install a program that some third party commands stopped working. For example, I tried installing miniconda with these two tutorials but the conda command does not work.

```
MacBook-Air:~ xxx$ conda
-bash: conda: command not found
```

( https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/user-guide/install/macos.html )

This in on an m1 mac 2020.

I have a feeling that I messed up multiple parts, because a lot of the third party programs that hosted their own commands stopped working. Worst case scenario it would be great to find a way to factory reset all aspects of the terminal so that I can get this command working.

Comment: Have you tried removing miniconda fully ?

Comment: I just did. ```rm -r ~/miniconda3/```. After installing, it gives me ```Thank you for installing Miniconda3! ```message. However, after typing ```conda``` it still states ```-bash: conda: command not found``` Oddly enough, after typing other third party commands such as ```brew``` I get a response.

Comment: Ok, now for some reason it is working after I pasted it in to my /usr/bin/ directory. I don't understand why it doesn't work when it is in my /Users/xxx/ directory though? Can anyone help me make programs work in there as well?

Comment: Just a guess, and I am not a MAC user, but sounds like you path might be messed up. echo $PATH will show you what you path is. If you could post that we can decided if that is the issue or not.